# How to install MediaTek MT7610U (RT2860) driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

MediaTek [provides Linux driver](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/) for USB Wi-Fi dongles based on MT7610U (chipset RT2860, I personally have ipTIME A1000UA). I downloaded [MT7610U USB V3.0.0.2](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/mt7610u-usb/) ([direct link](http://s3.amazonaws.com/mtk.cfs/Downloads/linux/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.tar.bz2)), extracted the archive and:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

Added following to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and rebooted:

```
blacklist rt2800usb
blacklist rt2870sta
blacklist rt2860sta
```

But the LED on the dongle did not turn on, nor there is any wireless connection available in network settings.

`ifconfig` gave only eth0 and lo, and `iwconfig` gave:

```
ra0   Ralink STA
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0
```

And `lshw -C network` gave:

```
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: ra0
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
```

I also tried the following:

```
sudo ifup ra0
Ignoring unknown interface ra0=ra0.
```

However, `sudo ifconfig ra0 up` did the trick and consequent `ifconfig` is giving:

```
ra0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:e5:99:f4:42:46
      inet6 addr: fe80::66e5:99ff:fef4:4246/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:368 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:94523 (94.5 KB)  TX bytes:12648 (12.6 KB)
```

But I still do not see wireless connection option in the network settings UI and after a reboot `ra0` is shown as disabled again.

Some relevant logs:

```
$ dmesg | grep rt28
[   19.488641] rtusb init rt2870 --->
[   19.490869] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870

$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
mt7650u_sta           927128  0

$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.

$ modinfo rt2800usb | grep 2870
firmware:       rt2870.bin
alias:          usb:v148Fp2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v8516p2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*
alias:          usb:v07B8p2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*

/var/log/syslog:
NetworkManager[986]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ra0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
NetworkManager[986]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ra0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
```

I tried by removing mt7650u and mt7630u from `CHIPSET` list in Makefile leaving only mt7610u, i.e.:

```
ifeq ($(CHIPSET),)
CHIPSET = mt7610u
endif
```

Also tried by moving `/etc/Wireless/RT2860STA` to `/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA` (as according to dmesg that rt2870 was the driver being loaded) with no success.

Same result with both Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (3.2.0-60-generic) and Linux Mint 16 64-bit (a friend's box). How do I install this driver?

Comment: Why use the RALink drivers ? have you tried with the default Ubuntu drivers ?

Comment: @Lawrence, what are default Ubuntu drivers? The dongle is not working out of box by just plugging it(if that's what you mean).

Comment: Ah right. The default drivers probably aren't configured to work with that chipset then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have no real tech knowledge but I can read and search well. I have mine up now with a blue light and showing decent statistics. Not sure what to do with an active ra0 yet. Maybe someone can help me too?

ANYWAY: I downloaded mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916 from mediatek
Edited according to these pages:

- http://www.ctheroux.com/ralink-rt5572-based-wifi-usb-dongle-setup-on-ubuntu-12-04/
  http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/229-ubuntu-precise-dlink-dwa160-revb2

I'm using kernel 3.2 crunchbang

Also added fyi-I previously had used the ndisgtk to install windows 7 drivers but that alone sure didn't help... so the above may be the only bit you need.  I also added the bin files included in the 7 directory to my firmware folder.

Sorry if I am confusing. Noticed you posted yesterday and thought I would drop in a novice response.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but still no success. However, there is a progress, now dmesg is giving: `[   18.838304] rtusb init rt2870 ---> [   18.840562] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870 [   20.581781] !!! rt28xx init fail !!! [   21.134603] !!! rt28xx init fail !!!`

Comment: Awesome, it is working! :) Just needed one more edit: changed `CHIPSET_DAT = 2860` to `CHIPSET_DAT = 2870` in `os/linux/config.mk` (at about line 663) for `mt7610u`. That's was it. After that `sudo make clean`, `sudo make`, `sudo make install` and rebooted. Voilà! Now I can see the wireless connection in network settings. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Since Kernel 4.19 there is native support for mt7610u. Fedora 30 and Ubuntu 19.04 has this kernel version. These distributions should work without any additional effort.

Comment: Did you test on any of these distributions?

Comment: I have built Kernel 4.19 on Ubuntu 18.04 and this worked fine, so should work on these distributions as well.

Answer (score 1):

The driver is still under development. It works perfectly fine. The only thing missing is the wifi power level indicator. LED is always off:
https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make an update to natura's answer mainly because I bought a Cisco AE6000 a year ago and wasn't able to use the device even after initially building the `/sanrath/mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit` driver. With the comment from ozbek about changing the ./os/linux/config.mk `CHIPSET_DAT` variable to `2870`, running `sudo make && make install` resulted in a fully working USB wireless adapter.

The steps are:

- Download `/sanrath/mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit` from BitBucket
- Change line `:671` to `CHIPSET_DAT = 2870`
- `sudo make && make install`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another driver, which claims to improve upon the original Mediatek driver.

https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u