# Cannot install MediaTek MT7610U (RT2860) driver

Tags: wifi-driver

I tried following the instructions of another question here: [How to install MediaTek MT7610U (RT2860) driver](https://superuser.com/questions/738096/how-to-install-mediatek-mt7610u-rt2860-driver?newreg=8d89a1da4ab5420caf9654be4caff186) but unfortunately even the first step fails.

Let me step back a bit:
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

```
uname -a
Linux anpan-GA-970A-D3 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 20 10:50:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 2109:0812  
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Relevant dmesg output:

```
[  797.428217] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  797.576438] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=7610
[  797.576447] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  797.576452] usb 2-1: Product: WiFi
[  797.576456] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  797.576460] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
```

The MediaTek one is the device in question. Searching the ID brought me to the question above and a link to the drivers from the MediaTek website.

I tried to follow the instructions of that question, but I couldn't even compile the driver:

```
make[2]: *** [/home/anpan/tmp/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/anpan/tmp/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-77-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

build-essential and linux-headers-generic are both installed.

Comment: What OS/distro?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. I edited the post with uname -a output