# How to install drivers for mt7610u Mediatek

Tags: usb

Please,I'm a very beginner I saw the"Ozbek"post
([How to install MediaTek MT7610U (RT2860) driver](https://superuser.com/questions/738096/how-to-install-mediatek-mt7610u-rt2860-driver))
,made in 2014.I have a usb wifi adapter with "lsusb"0e8d:7610 Mediatek,with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,but unfortunately I don't understand if it can work for me and what I have to do .Can someone give me some help,please.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no working drivers at this moment, especially if your kernel is pretty new. I have kernel 4.8.41 or something like that ( type in terminal to know your version: uname -r ) and none of these "fixed" versions work.

You can try, especially if you have kernel version number less than mine (4.4 for example) to install one fixed driver.

First of all type in terminal (go first to /home/yourusername/Downloads for example):

```
Sudo apt-get install git
```

When its done, type or copy paste:

```
Git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
```

Then:

```
cd mt7610u

Sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

When its done:

```
Sudo make
```

When its done, if no errors:

```
Sudo make installfw

Sudo depmod -a
```

Then:

```
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

If that insmod doesnt work, for example error with symbol, type:

sudo modprobe mt7610u

If it gives error, not found, then:

```
Sudo cp mt7610u.ko /path/which/error/message/said
```

And then again:

```
sudo modprobe mt7610u
```

If you get kernel panic/your system freezes, remove your dongle, restart from button, go to terminal, follow what answer here says:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/521222/how-to-unload-a-kernel-module-which-is-in-use

Then type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Then put your dongle back. Unfortunately, the driver does not work in this case, and you can look for updates for example in ulli-kroll page of github. (Not my driver, but for me seems that that is the best of current ones)